# JQuery Xeditable is not working with Angular2

Tags: jquery, angular, x-editable

I am using JQuery xeditable with Angular2 as given below. But, it the xeditable popup is opening only once.

Can anyone help me on this?.

Code snippet are as given below
Component class:

```
@Component({
  //some code here..
})
export class ClientDetailsComponent {
  ngOnInIt() {
    $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';
    $.fn.editable.defaults.emptytext = '';
    $('#comments').editable({
      'rows ':4,
     'inputclass':'word-wrap newComments',
      onblur:'cancel'
    });
  }

  public showpCommentBox() {
   $('#comments').editable('show');
  }
}
```

Html Code:

```
<a class="comments vertical-top word-wrap" 
   id="comments" data-type="textarea" 
   data-pk="1" data-url="" 
   (click)="showpCommentBox()"
   data-title="Enter comments">
   <i class="pe-7s-pen fa-1x text-primary text-left" title="Click to enter comments">
</a>
```

Comment: Can you make a plnkr or jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is 'contenteditable' attribute `<h1 contenteditable="true">Something</h1>` you can try it as alternative...

Comment: I have add below code to the component file as below:
$('#show').on('click', function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                $('#comments').editable('show');
            });

It is working now but after clicking once.. Can you help me if i am missing anything.